# Python RGB to grayscale conversion (ExGG) matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to write a function which does conversion from RGB to grayscale image. Values in grayscale image are calculated using ExGG (green extraction) method. Values are calculated as follows:

```
ExGG = (2 * g - b - r) * g
```

Where

```
r = R' / (R' + G' + B'),
g = G' / (R' + G' + B'),
b = B' / (R' + G' + B')
```

and *R', G'* and *B'* are normalized values from an RGB image in range [0, 1].

I have managed to come up with following pixel-wise solution:

```
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            (R, G, B) = image[i][j]
            RGB_sum = (R + G + B)
            r = R / RGB_sum
            g = G / RGB_sum
            b = B / RGB_sum
    
            # ExGG
            output[i][j] = ((2 * g) - b - r) * g
```

Where image is normalized RGB image (dtype is float64).

This element-wise calculation is providing correct result but it seems to be pretty slow, therefore i want to update this function to perform matrix operation instead of element-wise approach. Also, if anyone knows a way to perform these operations faster feel free to share.

Comment: I guess you are doing this for educational proposes, and I guess you know that this can be easly solved using cv2:
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Comment: @[AgustinGonzalezRibas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10418924/agustin-gonzalez-ribas) as specified in question, i do not need regular BGR2GRAY conversion but instead need grayscale image that represents "greenness" of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(4,4,3)
rgb_sum = np.sum(img, axis = 2)
img_rgb = img / rgb_sum[:, :, None]
r = img_rgb[:, :, 0]
g = img_rgb[:, :, 1]
b = img_rgb[:, :, 2]
output = ((2 * g) - b - r) * g
```